# Sum over a formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheet and I need to add a lot of stuff like

```
(ABS(A1)+A1)/A1+ (ABS(A2)+A2)/A2+...+ (ABS(A10)+A10)/A10
```

but I don't want to write out the sum each time for each term A1,A2,A3,..., A10

Is there a way to write the sum more concise? like

```
SUM( (|x| + x)/x : for x from A1 to A10)
```

I know that's not correct but that is what I want.

Comment: Have you tried grabbing the square corner of the cell containing the formula and dragging it down the column (for example). If certain cell refs are fixed, use the $ sign to make the cell reference absolute (such as $A$1) otherwise the cell ref will increment as you drag it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `Arrayformula` to achieve your goal.

You don't need to drag down a formula nor specify cells. This will work for every correct calculation in column A:

`=Sum(Arrayformula(Iferror((Abs(A2:A8)+A2:A8)/A2:A8,"")))`

[image]

or ignore `iferror` if you are sure `A2:A8` contains numbers (and not text or blank elements):

`=Sum(Arrayformula((Abs(A2:A8)+A2:A8)/A2:A8))`

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain a little bit what each of the items mean?

For example, I do not want to sum over the entirety of column A, suppose I only want to sum from A2 to A8 specifically

Comment: `Abs(A1:A)+A1:A)/A1:A` is your current solution. The difference is that instead of applying it to just a single element you can apply it to a range of elements `A1:A`. To apply it to a range of elements you need to use `arrayformula`. You don't want to apply it for every cell in column `A` but only for the ones which have a value (non blank value). To do that you can use `iferror` to prevent empty cells from being used by the formula. @ChristopherRose

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand. For example, the solution I want should not be a matrix, but should be a single number. Also, for the A column you wrote in your example, the sum I want should be 3 but your sum has 2 three times (or is it 0?) -- I don't understand

Comment: @ChristopherRose I updated my answer. Check it again.